# MySQL update a field using info in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I make an update of this tables?:

**Products** table

- IdProd [PK]
- Description
- Cost

**Transactions** table

- IdTransaction [PK]
- IdProd [FK]
- Quantity
- Total

I want to update the Total quantity finding the Cost in the products table, and multiplying it to my Quantity in my transactions table, but I don't really know how can I do this..

Comment: By keeping **calculated** `total` in the table, you lose normalization.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Update` from `JOIN` syntax

```
update Transactions A
INNER JOIN Products B
ON A.IdProd = B.IdProd
set A.Total = A.Quantity * B.cost
```

Comment: I'm getting this: ` 22:43:28 update transacciones A INNER JOIN productos B ON A.CodigoProducto = B.CodigoProducto set A.Total = A.Cantidad * B.Precio Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5 KG"' 0.016 sec
 `

Comment: @MarnyA.López - So quantity column has varchar data??. Its better to show some sample data